# Is there a way to increment/decrement windows brightness in steps of 5 rather than the default 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts

Most laptops have shortcut keys to increase / decrease monitor brightness on a windows laptop. For
example, the F11 and F12 keys (or somewhere around them).

The default brightness delta is 10 units which is sometimes too much. Is there a way I could fine-tune this setting (or through some other utility or hack) in order to set it to a lower delta (like 5 units)?

**Starting brightness value:**

[image: starting brightness value]

**After incrementing via hotkey:**

[image: After incrementing via hotkey]

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way I could fine-tune this setting?

Yes.

### Warning

The instructions below contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly.

Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.

For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

> 1. open regedit from start menu
> 2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\monitor\Parameters`
> 3. In the right pane, right click in an empty area, create New->`DWORD` and name it `MinimumStepPercentage`
> 4. modify the value to enter 00000005
> 5. After you restart, the brightness increments will be in fives.

Source: [brightness increments are at 10. possible to change to 5? - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/brightness-increments-are-at-10-possible-to-change/2617b9fb-515e-4d87-b898-d0cec0ec4790)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 11.

Comment: @spacerGIF Please ask a new question.

Comment: Answer/solution for Windows 11 is here: https://superuser.com/a/1835308/1244110