# Is there a way to increment/decrement Windows 11 brightness in steps of 5 rather than the default 10

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

New version of [Is there a way to increment/decrement windows brightness in steps of 5 rather than the default 10](https://superuser.com/q/1748522/756809),
since its answer only works for Windows 10.
This post is for Windows 11.

Most laptops have shortcut keys to increase / decrease monitor brightness on a windows laptop. For
example, the F11 and F12 keys (or somewhere around them).

The default brightness delta is 10 units which is sometimes too much. Is there a way I could fine-tune this setting (or through some other utility or hack) in order to set it to a lower delta (like 5 units)?

**Starting brightness value:**

[image: starting brightness value]

**After incrementing via hotkey:**

[image: After incrementing via hotkey]

Comment: What's wrong with the post that you linked to? Why is this copy required of that post?

Comment: @harrymc Its answer doesn't appear to work for Windows 11 so I was asked to ask a new question.

Comment: I made this fact clearer in the question. How are you changing the brightness, and are you sure that this is not a hardwired function of your keyboard?

Comment: With the Fn keyboard combos. It seems to adjust at the OS level, e.g. doesn't work in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11 I had to use keyboard shortcuts and powershell:

- Install "Microsoft PowerToys" from the Store
- Use the "Keyboard Manager" and the "Remap a shortcut" function to assign the below Actions to keys, like Win+F5 and Win+F6:

  - Action: Run Program
  - App: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
  - Args:

    - Decrease brightness: `(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1, [math]::Max((Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightness).CurrentBrightness - 1, 0))`
    - Increase brightness: `(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1, [math]::Min((Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightness).CurrentBrightness + 1, 100))`
  - Elevation: Normal
  - If running: Start another
  - Visibility: Hidden

Note:

- This will increase/decrease in steps of 1, but you can change it to +5 and -5 easily.

Comment: I don't seem to have the option to assign actions to keys, only remapping from one to another. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MToP.png

Comment: Click on the "Remap a Shortcut" button. The naming is a bit misleading. There you can set a key combination and assign an action to it. I will update my answer.